# Compiler Error CS0840

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, xml-serialization

I am getting this error in all of my classes but I am not sure why.`'Property name' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397743.aspx

I've read the MSDN article but I can't see what body or accessor is missing. What have I done wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ThereIsOnlyRules
{
[Serializable()]
public class ArmyListing
{
    public ArmyListing();

    [XmlElement("army")]
    public List<Army> listing { get; set; }

    public void SerializeToXML(ArmyListing armyListing)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArmyListing));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\40k.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, armyListing);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Army
{
    public Army();

    [XmlAttribute]
    [XmlArray("unit-category")]
    public List<UnitCategory> settingconstraints { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string armyName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class UnitCategory
{
    public UnitCategory();

    [XmlArray("unit-type")]
    public List<UnitType> setting { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string unitCategoryName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class UnitType
{
    public UnitType();

    [XmlArray("unit")]
    public List<Unit> setting { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string unitTypeName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Unit
{
    public Unit();

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string unitName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("composition")]
    public string compsition { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("weapon-skill")]
    public string weaponSkill { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("ballistic-skill")]
    public string ballisticSkill { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("strength")]
    public string strength { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("toughness")]
    public string T { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("wounds")]
    public string wounds { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("initiative")]
    public string initiative { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("attacks")]
    public string attacks { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("leadership")]
    public string leadership { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("saving-throw")]
    public string saveThrow { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("armour")]
    public string armour { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("weapons")]
    public string weapons { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("special-rules")]
    public string specialRules { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("dedicated-transport")]
    public string dedicatedTransport { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("options")]
    public string options { get; set; }
}
}

 //Form
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ThereIsOnlyRules
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArmyListing armyListing = new ArmyListing();
        armyListing.SerializeToXML(armyListing);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructors are invalid.

```
public Army();

public UnitCategory();

...
```